# Custom Views Field Formatter for List - show all values and indicate selected/not selected

Tags: views

new Drupal user here so please forgive any rookie assumptions or questions I may have.

I need to get all values (even those not selected) from a select list field in a view.

I'm trying to create a view that lists all the values in a select list. The list consists of when something is available (e.g. Winter, Spring, etc.). It's just as important to know when something is available as it is when it's not. However as I'm sure you already know, it only returns those items selected and not everything I need.

I've tried messing with the "rewrite results" trying Loops, IfElse, Multiple duplicate fields, etc.  Is this even possible and if so what the best way to go about it.  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Edit:

Example: 
Product_Name: product 1 Availability: **Winter | - | Summer | Fall**.

So I would want it to return all list options (selected or not), (" - " instead of "Spring" above because Spring is not selected for product 1) so I can write out the availability or add a " - " for not available.

Comment: Are you trying to list all values from some field, or are you trying to list nodes that have or don't have some list value chosen? You can use Filter for your list field and choose `Is one of` or `Is none of` to create a list of nodes that have those values, or a list of nodes that don't have those values. Can you include more information about what you're trying to do? How many lists? What should they show?

Comment: I'm trying to list all values from some field. For example: Product_Name: product 1 Availability: Winter| - | Summer | Fall. So I would want it to return all values (selected or not) so I can write out the availability or add a " - " for not available. As it is now, It only returns what is selected and every attempt I've made to "fill in the blanks" has not worked. Please let me know if I'm not making sense.

Comment: Thank you, it seems you need a custom Views Field formatter for List fields, or you might get away with Views PHP module or similar, to get all the possible values and not only the selected ones.